# Hirzebruch's $L$-polynomial and $\mathbb{C}P^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, projective-space, characteristic-classes

Hirzebruch's $L$-polynomial is the formal power series
\begin{equation}
L(x) = \frac{x}{\tanh x} = 1 + \frac{x^2}{3} + \cdots
\end{equation}

This defines a multiplicative sequence and a genus $L(M)$ for an oriented manifold.  See the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_of_a_multiplicative_sequence).

Let $n = 2k$ be an even positive integer.  Hirzebruch's signature theorem, applied to the $4k$-manifold $\mathbb{C}P^n$, tells us that
\begin{equation}
\langle L(\mathbb{C}P^n), [\mathbb{C}P^n] \rangle = 1.
\end{equation}

I'm wondering whether this can be shown directly without appealing to the signature theorem.  For example, in the case of a 4-manifold $M$, direct computation with symmetric polynomials shows that
\begin{equation*}
L_2(M) = \frac{c_1^2 - 2c_2}{3}
\end{equation*}

I also know that the Chern classes of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ are $c(\mathbb{C}P^n) = (1+y)^{n+1}$ for a generator $y \in H^2(\mathbb{C}P^n)$, so specializing to $n = 2$, $M = \mathbb{C}P^2$,
\begin{equation*}
L_2(\mathbb{C}P^2) = \frac{(3y)^2 - 2(3y^2)}{3} = y^2
\end{equation*}
which when paired with the fundamental class gives $1$, as wanted.

When $n$ is larger, the computations get very messy.  Is there some trick to painlessly compute $\langle L(\mathbb{C}P^n), [\mathbb{C}P^n] \rangle = 1$?

Comment: You can conjecture the signature theorem by conjecturing that the $L_i$ exist and determining what they must be using the fact that the signature of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ is always $1$. The computation involves using Lagrange inversion, and will also prove this fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a method in [Dan Freed's notes on bordism](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C/Notes/lecture8.pdf).  It's very, very slick, and I'll sketch it below for completeness.

The main difficulty with the direct calculation is the use of "formal Chern roots" for the tangent bundle $T\mathbb{C}P^n$.  If $T\mathbb{C}P^n$ were a sum of line bundles, then there would be no need to symmetrize the product and the calculation would be easier.  The key insight is that while $T\mathbb{C}P^n$ is not a sum of line bundles, it *is* stably equivalent to $(L^*)^{\oplus n+1}$, where $L$ is the tautological line bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^n$.  And since Chern classes are stable, the computation of the $L$-class can be done with $(L^*)^{\oplus n+1}$ instead.

In other words, since $c_1(L^*) = y$, the generator in $H^2 (\mathbb{C}P^n)$, we have
\begin{equation*}
L(\mathbb{C}P^n) = L((L^*)^{\oplus n+1}) = \left(\frac{y}{\tanh y}\right)^{n+1}
\end{equation*}

To find the coefficient of $y^n$ in this product, we can use the method of residues (the integral is quite fun to do), and we conclude that if $n$ is even then $\langle L(\mathbb{C}P^n), [\mathbb{C}P^n] \rangle$ is 1.